# JavaScript parse string and extract numbers

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the Total sent, Total Success and Total Error count from the following string.

**`03/07/2017 17:11:28.5323 to www.google.com : 65.199.32.57 65.199.32.20 65.246.5.55 65.199.32.58 Total Sent: 107 Total Success: 107 Total Errors: 0   0 : 11  : 93 : 15.32/`**

I have tried the following so far but haven't got success yet. 
The variable res holds above string.

Below results in error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null"

```
var matches = res.match(/(\d+)Total Sent(\d+)/);  
console.log(matches[1]);
console.log(matches[2]);
```

This results in a concatenated array with all numbers in the string which is not something I want.

```
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
var numArr = res.match(numberPattern);
console.log(numArr);
```

I want

```
Total Sent = 107
Total Success = 107
Total Error = 0.
```

Comment: `/(\d+)Total Sent(\d+)/` doesn't match because `Total Sent` is no *preceded* or *followed* by a digit. You want `/Total Sent: (\d+)/`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks that really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) function

Example :

var String=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("Total Sent: ")+1,str.lastIndexOf(" ")); //to get Total Sent value

Answer (score -1):

```
var input = '03/07/2017 17:11:28.5323 to www.google.com : 65.199.32.57 65.199.32.20 65.246.5.55 65.199.32.58 Total Sent: 107 Total Success: 107 Total Errors: 0   0 : 11  : 93 : 15.32/';

var match = input.match(/Total (\w+): (\d+)/g);

console.log(match);
// ["Total Sent: 107", "Total Success: 107", "Total Errors: 0"]

var output = match.join('\n').replace(/\:/g, ' =');

console.log(output);
/* 
   Total Sent = 107
   Total Success = 107
   Total Errors = 0
*/
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it were formatted as code, and if you explained the method you used.